# how can i write f(first,y) in matlab?

Tags: matlab

can you please help me?, i can't explain my question clearly, I define x & y ,i can write plot(f(end,y)) ,but I want to know that how can i must type this code for f(first,y)?thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"f(first,y)" is `f(1,y)`

Comment: i mean the "first" element (for expample) in a array

Comment: '1' is the first element, just as 'end' is the last.

Comment: @sam: yes, that's exactly what my solution does.

Answer (score 0):

Is `f()` a function? If so, are you wanting to pass the first element of `y` to `f()`? You can do this with `f(y(1))`.

Perhaps the MATLAB documentation on [Matrix Indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html) would help you?

Comment: @sam: Don't worry too much. The better you know a language, the better you learn to ask questions - and vice versa.